# When my model is in the "becameError" state, how do I find the error details?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am calling save() on a model object and the "becameError" method is being called in the model.  How do I find the error details?  The only parameter sent to "becameError" is the record in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save returns a promise, in the failing route of the promise the error is passed as an arg.

```
record.save().then(
 function(){ 
   //passed
 },
 function(error){
   //failed
 });
```